# Inserting new rows does not adjust the formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 6 sheets in an excel workbook. Cell A3 of sheet 6 contains following formula

> =SUM(Sheet1:Sheet5!A3)

, cell A4 of sheet 6 contains

> =SUM(Sheet1:Sheet5!A4)

and A5 of sheet 6 contains

> =SUM(Sheet1:Sheet5!A5).

Now I want to add a row between Row 4 and 5 in every sheet and the formula in new cell of the row A5 in Sheet6 contains the following formula

> =SUM(Sheet1:Sheet5!A5).

But when I do that the final sheet formula for cell A6 (previous A5) is still the same as before ie `=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet5!A5)` instead of `=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet5!A6)`. Why is this occurring and how to avoid this problem?

Pls dont suggest me to manually change formulas in `Sheet6` as there are thousands of rows in it to change. I tried but not succeded

Comment: If the formula is as simple as that, you can drag and fill the formula to the succeeding cells (A6 onwards) after inserting the row. It will then be adjusted automatically.

Comment: But there are many subtotal formulas in rows in between. I cant drag them blindly in totality.

Comment: How do we know that context?

Comment: As what @P.b mentioned, you didn't mention that. The only way I can think of right now is to change your formula to another that will handle inserting of rows in the future but again that will not save you from editing 1000 formulas.

Comment: You may be able to link it to an index match, but without any details we can't tell

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy your problem and found that re-dragging the formula on Sheet 6 reset the formula correctly and reflected the new row I added on sheets 1 to 5.
[Test Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyHpc.png)

Therefore I think you can drag the formula down even over 1000's rows to refresh the final sheet.

Comment: But as I previously mentioned in one of the comments, there are many subtotal formulas in rows randomly in between. I cant drag the revised formula till end due to that constraint